# Why am I unable to console.log the current state after I set the state in an async function within a useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to set the state of a variable which will be used as a query to fetch data, however after setting the state of this variable and then trying to console.log it, I see nothing in the console. However, when I make another request with a different query, the console shows the value of the first variable and then fetches the data for the last request.

How can I make it so that the console logs the variable and fetches the data the first time, instead of having a 1 query delay?

Here is the code if it's helpful:

```
React.useEffect(() => {

        console.log("useEffect");

        const getToken = async () => {

            console.log(formattedPlayer);
            setPlayer(formattedPlayer + "01");
            console.log(player);

            const result =  await bbstats.getPlayerStats(
                player,
                "totals"
              );
          
              //doing stuff with fetched data
    
        }

        getToken();     

    }, [props.player]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is [setState is asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). Which means that logging the state before and after its respective setState, won't work as expected.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect");

    const getToken = () => {
        console.log(formattedPlayer);
        setPlayer(async (currentPlayerValue) => {
            console.log(currentPlayerValue);
            var newPlayerValue = formattedPlayer + "01";
            const result =  await bbstats.getPlayerStats(
                newPlayerValue,
                "totals"
            );
            //doing stuff with fetched data
            return  newPlayerValue;
        });
    }
    getToken();
}, [props.player]);
```

In case you need to perform some state update inside `setPlayer`, it's just better to create another `useEffect` depending on the `player` state.